# 'Save', 'Save & New', 'Save & Exit', 'Cancel', 'Cancel & Exit'

Tags: save, close, cancel

So we have a form (not a modal), in our desktop software application.

There is a View mode and an edit/create mode for this form. The view mode is a summary of all the data from the create/edit mode.

Is it too much to have the following action buttons in create/edit mode described below:

SAVE - Saves the data and returns the screen to view mode.

SAVE & NEW - Saves the shown data and clears the form for a new entry.

SAVE & EXIT - Saves the form data and backs up one screen.

CANCEL - Does NOT Save the form data and goes into view mode.

CANCEL & EXIT - Does NOT save the data and backs up one screen.

Comment: Why not break them out into separate buttons?

Comment: yes, they will be separate buttons, but is it 'too much' or 'too many buttons' or too many actions for one form?

Comment: Yes, it is too much. Way too much.

Comment: What does “backs up one screen” (_exit_) mean?

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking off of what sjsteve is saying, it sounds unnecessary.

It sounds like 'Save' saves the current form, but stays on the page whereas save and exit saves and goes back to the screen before you get into the edit/create mode. Is it necessary to require the user to save? Can the saving happen after the user makes a change?

The options including exit seem superfluous. Let the user navigate the app, don't get too worried about providing them with every option.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea, it will confuse your users and there is no need. 
The `EXIT` function seems to be only for the view mode, so you don't need it on edit or create forms. The edit and create forms only need `SAVE` and `CANCEL`, only when saving a new form, prompt the user what to do next, create a new form or return to view mode. On the edit mode, both buttons would return to view mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's unnecessary. Do you know what the most common actions your users take? For example, I use 'command + s' to save all my documents, so I would never use 'Save and Exit' or 'Save and New'.

I would go with the least amount of options, and if your users provide you feedback with suggested improvements, then you can make them for version two.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is too much. Ideally an edit form need to have only 'SAVE' and 'CANCEL' buttons.

- From your question it seems there are 3 options after 'SAVE' - return screen to view mode, clears form for new entry, back up one screen. Which is the most commonly used action? Put that as the default behavior after 'SAVE'.
- Let 'CANCEL' clear the entries from the form or reverts form back to initial state which was presented to the user. Next step of action should be taken by the user, either he wants to exit or re-enter data.